# Console.WriteLine release mode compilation

Tags: c#, reverse-engineering, release-mode, console.writeline

I am writing a quite big project in C#. It's sort of a gameguard system, that prevents players from cheating at multiple levels, including local tunneling and advanced network encryption with multiple algorithms.

The question is about Console.WriteLine method. I'm using it a lot in my program, because its hard to track progress on multiple threads, without proper output. Is there any way, people can capture this output during runtime? It contains some sensitive informations. The application is build in release mode and obfuscated later (post-build script).

Should I rather use Debug.WriteLine method? Protecting application from being reverse-engineered is a priority for me. I read, that Debug's method isn't even compiled into code, in release mode. On the other hand, Console.WriteLine has some cool overloads.
Is there any way I can keep Console method and protect it, from unauthorized access?

Comment: How about you don't use Console.WriteLine and log stuff into a secure location?

Comment: @tnw He doesn't need to secure it; he just needs all of the console writes to be removed from the release build entirely, and to only exist in the debug builds.

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine` should have enough overloads to cover everything that `Console.WriteLine` can take.  It will box some of the system value types such as `bool` and `int`, unlike `Console`, so it's a *tad* less efficient, but as it's only for debug builds that really shouldn't matter to begin with.  Just use that.

Comment: @tnw I am also saving encrypted log (which logs action code, only I have desription of actions), but that doesn't show any usefull decrypted stuff during debugging in VS, its encrypted to protect log, from being a "crack-guide".

Comment: WriteLine with useful text seem like exactly thing you are trying to avoid in you resulting binary...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need your Console output at all in your release build, all the members in the Debug class are marked with [`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) which means that it will not be included in a release build. So yes, just use `Debug.WriteLine` if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) with conditional compilation so that it's not included in the Release build. Then you can just tail the log while you're debugging and get the same information without it being leaked to users.

Or, if you're more comfortable using Console.WriteLine, just wrap calls to that with conditional compilation, like so:

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```

Comment: Or even better, he could create a replacement class for `Console` that wrote to wherever he wanted; Debug, Console, or some logging API. But the best thing is, he wouldn't need `#if DEBUG` all over his code. He'd only need it in his replacement class and he could simply remove the `WriteLine()` implementation in release.

Comment: @Pete I think, that's the best way to go. Thank you, Sir.

Answer (score 1):

Like the Debug class methods, you can write methods that the compiler ignores calls to except for DEBUG builds. They just have to return `void` so the omitting the call does not have any effect. See [ConditionalAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The advantage over conditional compilation is that you don't need to litter your code with conditional directives.

If you like the Console methods, you can just wrap them in your own class.